# Installing checkinstall on fedora 20

Tags: linux, rpm, fedora20, checkinstall

I am a Linux noob and trying to build stuff from sources.

To keep it clean I'd like to use `checkinstall` but can't find it for Fedora 20
Is this possible ?

If so where is that ?

`yum install checkinstall` did not return any results

Answer (score 1):

The instructions listed in the link given by @JeffJohnson are not required. Just clone the git repository and the `make` will work just fine (follow the instructions from the `INSTALL` file). [You can find the link to the `git` repository here](http://checkinstall.izto.org/download.php).

Answer (score 0):

There are (untested by me) directions for building checkinstall at http://www.patrickmin.com/linux/tip.php?name=checkinstall_fedora_13